Error: does not match the required types of a Next.js Page. "DocumentIdPage" is not a valid Page export field during deployment in vercel. #67370
I was trying to deploy my next-app through vercel when I faced the following error:
Error:
does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
"DocumentIdPage" is not a valid Page export field.
The referenced code for the above error is as follows:
"use client";

import { Cover } from "@/components/cover";
import { Toolbar } from "@/components/toolbar";
import { Skeleton } from "@/components/ui/skeleton";
import { api } from "@/convex/_generated/api";
import { Id } from "@/convex/_generated/dataModel";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "convex/react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useMemo } from "react";

interface DocumentIdPageProps{
   params:{
       documentId: Id<"documents">;
   }
}

const DocumentIdPage = ({
   params
}:DocumentIdPageProps) => {
   const Editor = useMemo(() => dynamic(() => import("@/components/editor"), {ssr: false}),[])
   const document = useQuery(api.documents.getById,{
       documentId: params.documentId
   });
   const update=useMutation(api.documents.update);

   const onChange =(content: string) => {
       update({
           id: params.documentId,
           content
       });
   };
   if(document===undefined){
       return(
       <div>
           <Cover.Skeleton />
           <div className="md:max-w-3xl lg:max-w-4xl mx-auto mt-10">
               <div className="space-y-4 pl-8 pt-4">
                   <Skeleton className="h-14 w-[50%]"/>
                   <Skeleton className="h-4 w-[80%]"/>
                   <Skeleton className="h-4 w-[40%]"/>
                   <Skeleton className="h-4 w-[60%]"/>
               </div>
           </div> 
       </div>
       )
   }

   if(document===null){
       return(
       <div>
           Not found..
       </div>
       )
   }
   return ( 
       <div className="pb-40">
           <Cover url={document.coverImage}/>
           <div className="md:max-2-3xl lg:max-w-4xl mx-auto">
               <Toolbar initialData={document}/>
               <Editor onChange={onChange}
                   initialContent= {document.content}
               />
           </div>
       </div>
    );
}

export default DocumentIdPage;

Thanks in advance
Please help solve this problem

can you try to run npm run build locally and check the build status
